# Preferable to embeb dependencies on interfaces or let that job to the concrete classes?

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop

Here is a question that I have to face a lot when doing the design of my little apps. Is there a reason I should prefer

[image]

over

[image]

?

If yes, why? If not, are there any specific circunstances where there is a clear advantage in one approach over the other?

I tend to use the first approach, although I am not too sure why. I guess maybe it is because there may be some concrete implementation of IBonus that might not need a dependency at all, while the second approach is tieing me to something. A stub/mock class, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: I require skills in reading between the lines...

Comment: what's IBonus e.g.? Prefer what over what is not clear in the question.

Comment: Related question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039645/what-to-pass-via-constructor-and-what-to-pass-via-interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you understand the subject quite well. I agree with your argument that there might be an implementation which does not have the dependency and so it's best not to be tied down. I typically prefer the first approach, like you, for that very same reason and typically encourage that choice.

In general, I would say that if the dependency is an implementation detail, then it should be passed to the constructor of the concrete implementation. If the parameter is intrinsic  to the very definition  / nature of the computation, then it is better to pass in the parameter. Another situation where it is a good idea to pass the parameter in the interface is where mutation is concerned; for reentrance, it is better to pass a parameter that you modify over modifying the state of the implementation, so if any side-effects are expected, then I would encourage passing the object to be mutated. That aside, I agree with your view.

Comment: Concrete type constructor is not bound to definition of base type memebers and therefore gives more flexibiliy allowing to use dependencies of arbirtrary type.

Comment: @Basilevs, what are you talking about? How is that relevant? One can specify an interface / pure virtual base class as a parameter to the function. I'm not really seeing what you are arguing / stating.

Comment: Design of an interface covering all possible needs of every Bonus implementation might be a hard task. Moving dependencies to constructs looses the coupling of dependency and IBonus.

Comment: @Basilevs, I'm still not sure I understand what you are arguing... the interface should NOT leak implementation details... it should cover the needs of the users of the interface and should not expose anything about the implementation.

Comment: That's my point. Adding arguments like SomeDependency discloses implementation details for calculate.

Comment: Ok... so I don't understand why you posted that as a response to what I wrote; my point was that if SomeDependency is an implementation detail, then it shouldn't be a parameter, but if SomeDependency is not an implementation detail (SomeDependency is an interface, not a concrete type, and is intrinsic to the definition of the computation), then it should be included.